# row to column data

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have table named `AA`. I have 3 column in it namely `x,y,z`
. it has exactly one rows.

```
select * from aa;

x   y  z
10 20 30
```

I want output like

```
10
20
30
```

I have used below query

```
select x from AA union all select y from AA union all select z from AA ;
```

it is giving desired output. But I was told this is not feasible query. Can anyone of you provide me the best solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Oracle's [UNPIVOT Clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1#unpivot)

```
SELECT *
FROM AA
UNPIVOT (
    value FOR name IN (x AS 'x', y AS 'y', z AS 'z')
);
```

Will yield the result

```
name    value
----    -----
x         10
y         20
z         30
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b274a/1/0

---

Can it be generalized for more columns? Since the name of the columns needs to be known in advance, you cannot make it automatically consider additional columns, but of course, you can add more columns manually. Example also having other columns than the value columns:

```
CREATE TABLE AA (
    position NVARCHAR2(50),
    x        NUMBER(10),
    y        NUMBER(10),
    z        NUMBER(10),
    t        NUMBER(10)
);
INSERT INTO AA (position, x, y, z, t) VALUES ('pos 1', 10, 20, 30, 1);
INSERT INTO AA (position, x, y, z, t) VALUES ('pos 2', 11, 22, 33, 2);
INSERT INTO AA (position, x, y, z, t) VALUES ('pos 3', 34, 45, 56, 3);
```

You can query it with:

```
SELECT *
FROM AA
UNPIVOT (
    value FOR coord IN (x AS 'x', y AS 'y', z AS 'z', t as 'time')
);
```

and get

```
POSITION   COORD   VALUE
--------   -----   -----
pos 1      x        10
pos 1      y        20
pos 1      z        30
pos 1      time      1
pos 2      x        11
pos 2      y        22
pos 2      z        33
pos 2      time      2
pos 3      x        34
pos 3      y        45
pos 3      z        56
pos 3      time      3
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47f5f/2/0

---

If you really want to consider more columns dynamically, you would have to detect the available columns and create and execute the SQL statement dynamically. You cannot do it with "pure" SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is fine:

```
select x from AA union all
select y from AA union all
select z from AA ;
```

A more efficient version is a bit longer:

```
select (case when n = 1 then x
             when n = 2 then y
             else z
        end) as x
from (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) cross join
     AA;
```

More recent versions of Oracle support lateral joins and `apply`.  If you are using one, I would recommend:

```
select d(x)
from aa cross apply
     (select aa.x from dual union all
      select aa.y from dual union all
      select aa.z from dual
     ) d
```

Comment: cost of second query is more than first one. Can we do it using pivot table? I am not aware about cross apply..probably will be in 12 or 18c?

Comment: @OnkarTiwari . . . Lateral joins are in Oracle 12+.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple `UNPIVOT`,

```
SELECT
    col
FROM
    aa UNPIVOT ( col
        FOR val
    IN ( x,
         y,
         z ) );
```

I presume  your interviewer probably expected you to answer this?

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bc1e3/6)